# Matrix equation $A=PBP^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Suppose $P$ is invertible and $A=PBP^{-1}$ . Solve for $B$ in terms of $A$.

My attempt: I just left multiplied the equation by $P^{-1}$ and right multiplied it by $P$ so that I got $B=P^{-1}AP$. Is it possible to reduce this any further?

Comment: This is correct, and can't be reduced further without more information.

Comment: This is just what you need to do!